# What constructions of "elementary" mathematics are actually functors?

Tags: category-theory, examples-counterexamples, functors

I'm not looking for the usual simple examples of functors like the fundamental group or forgetful functors, what I'm looking for is some interesting examples of constructions from "elementary" mathematics that are secretly functorial. Like the derivative: it's actually a functor, with the chain rule expressing the composition rule of functors, but that's never discussed in basic Calculus courses.

Comment: What's the scope of what you call elementary mathematics ?

Comment: Acutally, the derivative in elementary calculus is **not** a functor. If you consider a much more abstract setting as in [Category of smooth manifolds](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/differentiation) then it is. Your example here is misleading.

Comment: Sure, that's what I meant. To interpret anything as a functor we're gonna need to define the categories we're working on and do some abstract non-elementary work, that's okay.

Comment: Do you *want* that to be discussed in a basic Calculus course?

Comment: Not really... And about the scope, I left it open for interpretation intentionally.

Answer (score 13):

One of my favourite examples of these is group actions.

A (monoid or) group $G$ can be considered as a category with a single object $\star$, whose morphisms $\star \to \star$ are the elements of $G$, and whose identity and composition are given by the unit element $e$ and the group operation, respectively.

A left action of $G$ on a set $X$ is precisely a functor $\alpha : G \to \mathbf{Set}$, where $G$ is considered as a category in the above sense.

- The set $X$ is the value of $\alpha(\star)$;
- For each $g \in G$, we obtain a function $\alpha_g = \alpha(g) : X \to X$;
- Functoriality expresses the fact that $\alpha_e = \mathrm{id}_X$ and $\alpha_{gh} = \alpha_g \circ \alpha_h$.

Likewise a right action on a set is precisely a functor $\alpha : G^{\mathrm{op}} \to \mathbf{Set}$.

Comment: And if you replace Set with the category Vect of vector spaces over some field, you get representations of $G$.

Answer (score 7):

The function that sends a set $X$ to its powerset $\mathcal{P}(X)$ is a functor; and interestingly, it is a functor in more than one way!

Probably the most natural way to make it into a functor is to define, given a function $f:X\to Y$,
$$\mathcal{P}(f):\mathcal{P}(X)\to \mathcal{P}(Y):A\mapsto f(A)=\{f(a)\mid a\in A\};$$
in other words, we send $f$ to the function "direct image by $f$". This is a functor, because (pretty much by definition) $g(f(A))=(g\circ f)(A)$ for all $f:X\to Y$, $g:Y\to Z$ and $A\subset X$.

But there is also the function "inverse image by $f$", defined as
$$\mathcal{P}'(f):\mathcal{P}(Y)\to \mathcal{P}(X):B\mapsto f^{-1}(B)=\{a\in X\mid f(a)\in B\}.$$
Note that here I've switched $X$ and $Y$; so it's not a functor on the category of sets, but from the opposite category of sets to the category of sets, or if you prefer a contravariant functor on the category of sets. Here the functoriality amounts to the fact that $f^{-1}(g^{-1}(C))=(g\circ f)^{-1}(C)$ for all $f:X\to Y$, $g:Y\to Z$ and $C\subset Z$.

Comment: This is a great example since many basic properties of functions are naturally described in terms of the "direct image" map, such as how a function is injective if and only if its direct image map is cardinality-preserving.

Answer (score 3):

In almost any course a (U.S.) undergraduate math major would take, the construction $F(X)=A \times X$ for fixed $A$ defines a functor from any reasonable category to itself (obvious action on maps).  This works for sets, (abelian) groups, topological spaces, vector spaces, rings, etc.  (Of course it works in any category with products, but I'm trying to keep it "elementary.")

Comment: I think we don't even need to fix $A$, we can just view $\times$ as a functor $\mathcal{C} \times \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C}$.

Answer (score 2):

Any homomorphism $f:G_1\rightarrow G_2$ between two groups, both considered as one object categories, is a functor from $G_1$ to $G_2$.

This is true for ring homomorphisms as well.

Comment: An interesting exercise is this: if two groups are equivalent as categories, are they isomorphic as groups?

Comment: Perhaps a more "elementary" version of my suggestion is this: the procedure of evaluation of a polynomial $f(x)\in{\mathbb R}[x]$ at a real number $a$ is a functor from ${\mathbb R}[x]$ to ${\mathbb R}$, both considered as one object pre-additive categories.

Answer (score 1):

As noted, differentiation is a functor in the category of (real, finite-dimensional) smooth manifolds. In particular, it maps every manifold $X$ to its tangent bundle $TX$, which is locally isomorphic to $X \times \mathbb{R}^{n}$ for appropriate $n$. In some sense, one might consider differentiation ''locally'' an example functor of the form $F(X) = A \times X$ described by @Randall (well, technically $X \mapsto X \times A$).

However, the functor maps smooth functions in a non-trivial way. For manifolds $X, Y$ and smooth $f: X \to Y$, the derivative $D(f): TX \to TY$ is the map
 $$ D(f): (x,v) \mapsto (f(x), df_{x}(v)) $$
where $df_{x}$ is the ordinary total derivative of $f$ at $x$.

Comment: $TX$ is not isomorphic to $X\times \mathbb{R}^n$ in general.

Comment: @Max How so? Is it the topology? I thought at least locally it is isomorphic (which I admit is quite different than being globally isomorphic).

Comment: Yes it is locally isomorphic but not globally; but imagine if it were, then vector fields would be much less interesting : a vector field would be essentially a map $X\to \mathbb{R}^n$, and that would be boring. Manifolds for which this isomorphism holds are called parallelisable (at least in french, I don't know the english word). It's equivalent to having $n$ vector fields $X_1,...,X_n$ such that for all $x$, $(X_1(x),...,X_n(x))$ is a basis of $T_xX$. In particulaf, a manifold for which there is such an isomorphism are always orientable (but it's not equivalent) : $\mathbb{R}P^2$ isn't

Comment: Butnit doesn't change the fact that $X\mapsto TX$ is a functor, simply i's a more interesting one